# Balanced Text Wrapping in \parbox

Tags: horizontal-alignment, boxes

Is there a possibility to balance the lines if a text has to be wrapped in a `\parbox`?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\begin{document}
    \parbox{35mm}{\centering This is text}

    \parbox{35mm}{\centering This is some more text}
\end{document}
```

outputs:

```
    This is text

  This is some more
        Text
```

while I would like to have

```
    This is text

    This is some
      more Text
```

Comment: Add ``\\`` after `some`

Comment: Try the package ragged2e and `\Centering`.

Comment: You could reduce the width of the \parbox, but just dividing the width of the line by the number of lines won't work reliably.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer could you post this as answer?

Comment: @white_gecko: No, you didn't post a minimal example so I won't bother with an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ragged2e and `\Centering`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\begin{document}
\parbox{35mm}{\centering This is some more text}
\parbox{35mm}{\Centering This is some more text}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is crude and slow, but it does what you want.

[image: centerbox]

```
\documentclass{article}
\parskip=3ex

\newcommand{\centerbox}[2]% #1 = max width, #2 = contents
{\begingroup% save registers
  \dimendef\height=0
  \dimendef\width=1
  \dimendef\test=2
  \settoheight{\height}{\parbox{#1}{\centering #2}}%
  \width=#1\relax
  \loop
    \advance\width by -1em
    \settoheight{\test}{\parbox{\width}{\centering #2}}%
    \ifdim\test=\height\repeat
  \advance\width by 1em
  \makebox[#1][c]{\parbox{\width}{\centering #2}}%
\endgroup}

\begin{document}
\parbox{30mm}{\centering This is some more text}

\centerbox{30mm}{This is some more text}
\end{document}
```