# How can I create balanced raggedright lines for headings?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, ragged2e

I have sectional headings (at all heading levels) that are set raggedright and unhyphenated. But the line distribution is unbalanced, so that when the heading is long you can get, say, one word orphaned on the next line.

The effect I want is similar to [CSS `text-wrap: balance`](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/css-text-wrap-balance/).

I can get good line balancing using `ragged2e` and its `\Centering` command, but for reasons I don't understand the `\RaggedRight` command doesn't get the same results.

In sum I want:

- raggedright headings
- no hyphenation
- balanced lines when the heading wraps

The solution needs to be handled in the preamble, as the text is automatically converted from HTML, so I can't insert line breaks.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

{\tiny normal centering}\\
\parbox{\textwidth}{\section*{\centering This is some random  text to test ragged line balance}}

\vspace{3em}

{\tiny ragged2e Centering}\\
\parbox{\textwidth}{\section*{\Centering This is some random  text to test ragged line balance}}

\vspace{3em}

{\tiny normal raggedright}\\
\parbox{\textwidth}{\section*{\raggedright This is some random  text to test ragged line balance}}

\vspace{3em}

{\tiny ragged2e RaggedRight}\\
\parbox{\textwidth}{\section*{\RaggedRight This is some random  text to test ragged line balance}}

\vspace{3em}

{\tiny this is what I want}\\
\parbox{\textwidth}{\section*{\RaggedRight This is some random  text \\to test ragged line balance}}

\end{document}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225533/balanced-text-wrapping-in-parbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some playing around, I have found a solution that works, based on @mickep's answer, but applied directly to sectional headings and thus avoiding the problems with `parbox`. I don’t really understand all that’s going on, so any suggestions or corrections are welcome.

- Create new `\BalancedRagged` command.
- Apply to sectional headings via `sectsty`.
- Include package `microtype` as this changes the spacing.
- Stretch for `\rightskip` adjusts the length of the first line(s): the larger it is, the more it wants to shift words onto the next line.
- Stretch for `parfillskip` elasticizes the final line: the smaller the stretch, the more it wants the final line to be the same length as the previous lines.
- `\spaceskip` is slightly more squeezy than the default, so some lines are on one line rather than two (see example 3).
- `\xspaceskip` doesn't seem to affect anything in these examples.
- Both `\spaceskip` and `\xspaceskip` can be omitted, leave it up to defaults.

For the MWE, for convenience I use `\section` to show defaults followed by `\subsection` to show the effects of `\BalancedRagged`.

- Example 1 shows that `\BalancedRagged` does not create new lines, even when the number of characters fills the line length exactly.
- Example 2 solves the major problem with the default settings, eliminating orphans.
- Examples 3 and 4 eliminate hyphenation in headings.
- Example 5 shows that it works in three-line headings too.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{microtype}

\protected\def\BalancedRagged{
\leftskip     0pt
\rightskip    0pt plus 10em
\spaceskip=1\fontdimen2\font plus .5\fontdimen3\font minus 1.5\fontdimen4\font
\xspaceskip=1\fontdimen2\font plus 1\fontdimen3\font minus 1\fontdimen4\font
\parfillskip  0pt plus 15em
\relax
}

\sectionfont{\large}%
\subsectionfont{\large\BalancedRagged}%

\begin{document}

\noindent 1.
\section*{This tests sectional headings which are this exact line length}
\subsection*{This tests sectional headings which are this exact line length}
\bigskip
2. 
\section*{This tests the balancedness of the lines in section headings, etc.}
\subsection*{This tests the balancedness of the lines in section headings, etc.}
\bigskip
3.
\section*{This shows the line’s resistance when it comes to hyphenation}
\subsection*{This shows the line’s resistance when it comes to hyphenation}
\bigskip
4.
\section*{This too shows the line’s resistance when it comes to hyphenation}
\subsection*{This too shows the line’s resistance when it comes to hyphenation}
\bigskip
5.
\section*{This tests the balancedness of the lines in three-line section headings, which, even though you want to avoid them, do occur}
\subsection*{This tests the balancedness of the lines in three-line section headings, which, even though you want to avoid them, do occur}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot illustrating the effects of BalancedRagged]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an uncentered version of my linked solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\balancebox}[2]% #1 = max width, #2 = contents
{\begingroup% save registers
  \dimendef\height=0
  \dimendef\width=1
  \dimendef\test=2
  \settowidth{\test}{#2}% single line check
  \width=#1\relax
  \ifdim\test>\width
    \settoheight{\height}{\parbox{#1}{\raggedright #2}}%
    \loop
      \advance\width by -1em
      \settoheight{\test}{\parbox{\width}{\raggedright #2}}%
      \ifdim\test=\height\repeat
    \advance\width by 1em
  \fi
  \parbox{\width}{\raggedright\strut #2\strut}%
\endgroup}

\begin{document}
\parbox{30mm}{This is some more text\strut}

\balancebox{30mm}{This is some more text}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works in the MWE but creates a bunch of errors in edge cases. Main ones are:

- It messes with page breaks, so that section headings end up as widows
- For single word headings it gives a "dimension too large" error

Comment: For a single word it will try to break the word using negative widths.  Probably better to pre-test for that case.  Not sure what the other problem is, since \parbox is unbreakable and the final height is the same as the original height.  I suspect you are using too large a value for the maximum width.

Comment: I added a single line check.

Comment: Thanks, this solves the single word problem, but creates a new one: now it doesn't work with sectional heading: this worked with the former version, but not any more (\balancebox{\textwidth}{\section*{This is some more text to test balanced line breaks and such}}).

Comment: And as for the page breaking problem, this seems to have something to do with the fact that the heading is now seen by LaTeX as a paragraph? So it doesn't respect the sectional page breaking. But vertical height is messed with even without sectional headings. You've made a fixed parskip in your example, but if you remove that and let the parskip glue do what it does, the paragraph spacing is uneven.

Comment: LaTeX thinks \parbox is a single word, not a paragraph.  OTOH, [b] might help.  Starting  and/or ending with a \strut will help.  Also, try \linewidth instead of \textwidth for the maximum width.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one shall not have macros inside sections like this, and maybe this is not the correct way of doing it, but this seems to work.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{ragged2e}

\protected\def\MaybeRight{%
\leftskip     0pt
\rightskip    0pt plus 5em
\spaceskip    \fontdimen2\font
\xspaceskip   \fontdimen2\font
\parfillskip  0pt
\parindent    0pt}

\begin{document}

{\tiny this is what I want}\\
\parbox{\textwidth}{\section*{\RaggedRight This is some random  text \\to test ragged line balance}}

{\tiny this is what I want}\\
\parbox{\textwidth}{\section*{\MaybeRight This is some random  text to test ragged line balance}}

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks, I've adapted your answer to make my solution.